# Validate User via remote active directory

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory

I have a strange scenario that I hope you guys can help with, I need to validate the current logged in user with active directory, this isn't a problem if they are on the network but in some instances they will be on another network (visiting clients) and in order for them to use the software they need to validate against AD.

At present I am using the following code am I correct in saying this will work locally and remotely? If not how can I get it to validate credentials?

```
DomainServer = new ActiveDirectory(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010, "LDAP://DOMAIN.NAME", "https://exchange.domain.name/ews/exchange.asmx");
DomainServer.connect();
if (!DomainServer.isConnected())
{
    domain_errors = "Unable to connect to Active Directory.";
}

class ActiveDirectory
    {
        private ExchangeService _ExchangeServer;
        private DirectoryEntry _searchRoot;
        private DirectorySearcher _search;
        private SearchResult _searchresult;
        private ExchangeVersion _ExchangeVer;
        private string _ActiveDirectoryAddress; 
        private string _ActiveDirectoryURL; 

        public ActiveDirectory(ExchangeVersion Ver, string ActiveDirectoryAddress, string ActiveDirectoryURL)
        {
            _ActiveDirectoryURL = ActiveDirectoryURL;            
            _ActiveDirectoryAddress = ActiveDirectoryAddress;
            _ExchangeVer = Ver;            
        }
        public void connect()
        {
            _ExchangeServer = new ExchangeService(_ExchangeVer);
            _ExchangeServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            _ExchangeServer.Url = new Uri(_ActiveDirectoryURL);
            _ExchangeServer.Timeout = 60;
        }
        public bool isConnected()
        {            
            if (_searchRoot.Properties.Count > 0){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When they are on another network, do they have a VPN connection to your network?  Is this a stand-alone application, or does it make other connections to your network (database connections for instance)?

Comment: kind of both lol, there won't be a VPN setup, there is a port tunnel setup to an off-site database engine which I was thinking I could validate against that way but unsure how I would go about updating the database with the credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows caches usernames and passwords on local machines so that a domain user can login even if the machine, such as a laptop, is not connected to the domain.  Since Windows is essentially handling the authentication for you, all you really need to do is authorize who can use the software.  I can think of a few possibilities.

First, in the database, you could maintain a user table with the SIDs and usernames of those users with access to the software.  When a user executes the program, check that the SID of the currently logged in user is in that table.  This way, you can restrict what users can actually execute the software without connecting to Active Directory.  This would also allow you to revoke access at the database level.

Secondly, does the database server have access to the Active Directory?  If so, create a group in AD for users with access to this system, then grant that group access in the database.  Set the database connection to use Windows authentication.  Therefore, if the person is in that group, they have access to the database.  Otherwise, they do not.  Then, you can control access just by adding or removing them from that group and security will be controlled at the database level.

Third (and I'm not a fan of this one), if you have a web server, run a web service (using HTTPS of course) that accepts a username and password and then use that web service to connect through your firewall and authenticate against AD.  Then, just return a result to your application.  This presents some security concerns with passing credentials to a web service and opening connections through the firewall.

Comment: My only issue is the software uses AD to get a list of users for Exchange integration, however if the connection isn't there then I can just disable these features.

Database doesn't have access to AD and the web service wouldn't work either (its a linux web server)

Comment: Another option is to have a scheduled job that runs (perhaps nightly) and updates a table in the database with the users from AD.  Then, the application could just pull from that table.  The data wouldn't be real time, but maybe close enough...?

Comment: Accepted answer, I realized that I could talk to exchange as well so I validate against that as well :)